# What does "it" in "it go" refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Batman* (2022), Riddle says to Batman:

> Riddle: Do you know what being an orphan is? It's 30 kids to a room. Twelve years old and already a drophead,
> numbing the pain. You wake up screaming with rats chewing your fingers. And every winter one of the
> babies die because it's so cold. But, oh, no.
> Let's talk about the billionaire with the lying, dead daddy
> because at least the money makes **it** go down easy.

What does "it" in "it go" refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full line (according to IMDB) is:

> **The Riddler** : You know, I was there that day. The day the great Thomas Wayne announced he was running for mayor, made all those promises. Well, a week later he was dead, and **everybody just forgot about us. All they could talk about was poor Bruce Wayne**. Bruce Wayne, the orphan. Orphan. Living in some tower over the park isn't being an orphan. Looking down on everyone, with all that money. Don't you tell me. Do you know what being an orphan is? It's 30 kids to a room. 12 years old and already a drophead, numbing the pain. You wake up screaming with rats chewing your fingers. And every winter, one of the babies die because it's so cold. **But, oh, no. Let's talk about the billionaire with the lying, dead daddy, because at least the money makes it go down easy**.

I made the important parts **bold** for emphasis.

##### This shows us that `it` refers to **"talking about orphans"**.

The Riddler criticizes that people did not talk about the difficult lives of poor orphans, because these conversations would be uncomfortable and difficult They would not go down easy). Instead people focussed on Bruce Wayne who was an orphan but did not have to deal with the difficulties of poverty on top of that. That way they could shut their eyes to the suffering other orphans endured.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiom: "a tough pill to swallow" which refers to facts or news that is difficult to accept but is unavoidable. "Makes it go down easy" is referring to something that is normally hard to swallow.

So "it" refers to Wayne becoming an orphan, and the money made it easier for him in contrast to Riddle's experience.